# Hpergeometric Reduction with Mathematica

Tags: real-analysis, hypergeometric-function, mathematica

We know that:

$$\,_2F_1(a,b,b,z)=(1-z)^{-a}$$

But putting $b<0$ with $b$ integer Mathematica does not use the previous formula but generates the hypergeometric polynomial. For instance:

$$\,_2F_1(a,-2,-2,z)= \frac{1}{2} (2 + 2 a z + a z^2 + a^2 z^2)$$

I don't understand why this happens because the 2 pochammer should cancel in the hypergeometric definition also if they are negative. Any Idea?

Comment: The Mathematica documentation states under "Possible Issues" that "However, when there is a negative integer among common elements, `HypergeometricPFQ` is interpreted as a polynomial:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes down to how Mathematica interprets these types of special cases for the Hypergeometric function. Specifically, it is using [this definition](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.2.E5) so that your hypergeometric function is *interpreted* as
$$
\begin{aligned}
F(a,-2;-2;z)
&=\lim_{c\to-2}\lim_{b\to-2}F(a,b;c;z)\\
&=\lim_{c\to-2}\frac{a^2 z^2-2 a c z+a z^2-2 a z+c^2+c}{c (c+1)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2} (2 + 2 a z + a z^2 + a^2 z^2)\\
&=1 +a z +\frac{a(1+a)z^2}{2}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^2 \frac{(a)_k}{k!}z^k.
\end{aligned}
$$

Here the Mathematica code: `Limit[Hypergeometric2F1[a, -2, c, z], c -> -2]`.

So we see that the $(-2)_k$ terms do cancel out; however, the series also truncates to only the first three terms and thus does not gives the binomial result you expected.